# OSX 10.9.5 upgrade causes apache/php downgrade

Tags: macos, mac, apache, php

Today I installed the OSX 10.9.5 upgrade and it appears to have downgraded my Apache and PHP version.

Is there an easy way to reverse this *unwanted* downgrade?
Or do I have to reinstall apache via homebrew again?

Comment: Please explain what you had done to Apache on your system before the upgrade.

Comment: I had upgraded it to 2.4, upgraded php to 5.5, I had configured httpd.conf. That seems to be lost now. Looks like the upgrade simply blew away my old httpd.conf

Comment: PHP is no longer loading in a bunch of extensions like memcached.

Comment: I think if apache will use my homebrewed version of php that will probably sort things out for today.

Comment: How did you upgrade? Did you replace the system files or install in a different path?

Comment: I don't remember... it was a while ago. I didn't expect the fine folks at Apple to take such a brutal approach with my setup.

Comment: It looks like I only had the one install. So I guess I must have replaced the install.

Comment: `Henrys-MacBook-Pro:Sites $ locate httpd | grep httpd$
/Library/WebServer/share/httpd
/usr/sbin/httpd
/usr/share/httpd
/usr/share/zsh/5.0.2/functions/_lighttpd
Henrys-MacBook-Pro:Sites$ 
`

Answer (score 1):

I replaced the following line in httpd.conf:

`LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so`

With:

`LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.12/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so`

This seems to have restored a lot of my old setup and I can work again.

Comment: I guess the lesson here is to backup your apache config before you do an OSX upgrade.